Proper way to evaluate limits using asymptotics?
I was presented with the following expression:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{4x + 4} - 2}{x} $$
I was under the impression that you could figure out if the limit converges or not by simply looking at the leading terms in the numerator and the denominator. Since the numerator has only constant and $\sqrt{x}$ terms, whereas the denominator has an $x$, I assumed this limit would blow up to infinity.
However, algebraic manipulation shows that it is in fact equal to 1, so clearly my understanding of asymptotics is way off. I would like a way to quickly analyze such a limit to determine whether it converges or not before I start doing a lot of algebra on it. Obviously this example is pretty simple and I could just do L'Hopital to it, but if the expression is quite complicated, I'd like an algorithm for at least determining whether or not it's worth looking for a limit when all the terms are polynomials, you know?

why are you considering the behaviour at infinity if the limit is as $x\to 0$?

I'm not. At infinity the $x$ in the denominator would force the limit to $0$.

The asymptotic you consider only works as $x \to \infty$. As $x \to \infty$, one can develop a good asymptotic for the top as $2\sqrt{x}$, and one for the bottom as $x$, and that (correctly) implies that the function goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.
But as $x \to 0$, the top bit goes to a constant. That is, even though there's a $\sqrt{x}$ behavior, it's not a behavior that goes like $\sqrt{x}$ at infinity, or even at $0$, but it behaves like $\sqrt{x}$ at a regular point, basically at $x=4$. So, at a regular point, an asymptotic expression for the sqrt bit is $\sqrt{4x+4} \sim 2 + x ~~~(x \to 0)$, which does imply the correct limit.
Basically, your intuition that the asymptotic behavior of the top is enough to give the limit is right, but the sqrt doesn't behave like a sqrt near $0$ (which would indeed dominate the $x$ correction term as $x \to 0$, because $\sqrt{4x+4}$ is just at a regular point at $0$.

I guess what I don't understand is why $\sqrt{4x+4} \sim 2 + x $. I understand the constant is the dominant term but that makes me think $\sqrt{4x+4} \sim \sqrt{4} $. Where is that extra $x$ coming from?

That's the right intuition. The constant is the dominant, term, and, indeed, $\sqrt{4x+4} \sim \sqrt{4}$ is the leading order term. To get the next correction, it depends on where the point is. For a function near a singular point, one may often need exotic asymptotic behaviors, but for a function near a regular point, the next correction is next term in the Taylor expansion, which is how one can get $\sqrt{4x+4} \sim 2+x$. This is the easiest, and often a good first, case to check for asymptotic expansions, that by Taylor's theorem Taylor series are a good place to start (at regular points)

Ah, I see. It's because the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x+1} = 1 + \frac{x}{2}  - ...$.
So when checking the asymptotics, the fact that $O(\sqrt{x})$ contains $O(x)$ as $x \to 0$ should give me a hint to expand it until I hit an $x$ term?

More specifically it's the fact that $O(\sqrt{x+1}))$ is $O(1)$ as $x \to 0$. When a function is going to a constant, that's usually a hint it may have a regular expansion at that points. With some exceptions ($2+\sqrt{x}$, say), but that's a good rule of thumb

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{4x + 4} - 2}{x} =\lim_{x \to 0} 
\frac{2(\sqrt{x + 1} - 1)}{x}
$$
Using Taylor expansion for $\sqrt{x + 1}$ around $x = 0$:
$$
\sqrt{x + 1} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + o(x^3)
 \iff
\sqrt{x + 1} - 1 \approx \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + o(x^3)
$$
Therefore:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{4x + 4} - 2}{x}=\frac{2(\sqrt{x + 1} - 1)}{x} \approx \frac{x - \frac{x^2}{4} + o(x^3)}{x} = 1 - \frac{x}{4} + o(x^2)
$$
Taking the limit $x \to 0$, the term $-\frac{x}{4} + o(x^2)$ approaches $0$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{4x + 4} - 2}{x} = 1
$$
